# Add a line break in a flash notice rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add a line break into a flash notice. So far I have this

```
flash[:success] = "We will notify you when we go LIVE! #{<br />} Meantime, complete this quick survey so we can get to know your interest.
```

But it is incorrect. Does anyone know how to properly do this in the controller?

I am using ruby 2.2.1p85 & Rails 4.0.10

Comment: `flash[:success] = "We will notify you when we go LIVE! #{'<br />'.html_safe} Meantime, complete this quick survey so we can get to know your interest."
` try this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always a dirty way to do stuff in programming. Here you can create multi line array inside flash.

```
     flash[:success] = []
     flash[:success] = flash[:success] << "We will notify you when we go LIVE! "
     flash[:success] = flash[:success] << "Meantime, complete this quick survey so we can get to know your interest."
```

and display it like this

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <% value.each do |text| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will definitely work.

But the best way to do that is this

```
flash[:success] = "We will notify you when we go LIVE! <br> Meantime, complete this quick survey so we can get to know your interest.".html_safe
```

If this also doesn't work then try it another way

in controller set

```
flash[:success] = "We will notify you when we go LIVE! <br> Meantime, complete this quick survey so we can get to know your interest."
```

and in view display like

```
 <% flash.each do | value| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, value.html_safe %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: where would you hold the flash responses, not in the controller, right?

Comment: flash are stored like session variables you can set it's value  in controller   the only difference is it looses it's content after next request from client side.

Comment: the last way is giving me the error
    TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String): the html_safe way

Comment: first way in your answer gave me NoMethodError (undefined method `key?' for []:Array)

Comment: then in first case remove "key, " and try only with " | value |".

Comment: Actually all the above version works in my system with ruby 2.4 and rails 5.1.5 so if you specify your system version I might better help you in this regard. the key idea here is either put html tag and ask rails not to treat html as string or break the string into multiple line and save in array, iterate over array to get those broken statement that's it.

Comment: ruby 2.2.1p85 Rails 4.0.10 Made the changes, got the error TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):

Answer (score 2):

```
flash[:success] = "We will notify you when we go LIVE! <br> Meantime, complete this quick survey so we can get to know your interest."
redirect_to YOUR_URL, flash: { html_safe: true }
```

Comment: Did not work, I got the error NoMethodError (undefined method `html_safe=' for nil:NilClass) I am using ruby 2.2.1p85 Rails 4.0.10

Comment: root_path, flash[:success] { html_safe: true }= "We will..."  ?? Gives an error

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Rails 5.2.6. I wanted to have two lines in my flash message where the first line was a general message and the second line was built from a database table. This is the solution that I discovered.

```
@flash_message_string = "line1text<br>"

run method to append database values to @flash_message_string and build
the second line of the flash message

flash.now[:danger]   = "#{@flash_message_string}".html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `<br/>` tag without interpolation and it will work.

```
"We will notify you when we go LIVE! <br/> Meantime, complete this quick survey so we can get to know your interest."
```

Comment: Nope, i got an error 
    TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):